# Regex Match Spaces and Periods Between Specified Strings

Tags: regex, obsidian

I am trying to match all characters that would invalidate the tags in the frontmatter of my obsidian markdown file, so that I can replace them with underscores. The file's metadata looks like this:

```
tags: [book,timeline, J. D. Salinger, Margaret Atwood, O'Connell]
```

Ideally, I'd be able to turn this into:

```
tags: [book,timeline,J_D_Salinger,Margaret_Atwood,O_Connell]
```

Is there any way to do this?

I was able to match all of the content between the square braces, but I was unable to isolate the spaces.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your attempts as well?

Comment: maybe something like this https://regex101.com/r/Z54P12/latest? In a second step you could replace `__` with `_`.

Comment: @DuesserBaest If you have an answer, post it as such. By the way, just add a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?<!,)[ .']+(?!.*\[)
```

and replace with

```
_
```

See here: https://regex101.com/r/Z54P12/latest

`(?<!,)` ensures no comma is preceeding (avoids `a, b,...` turning into `a,_b,...`)

`[ .']+` matches a set of special characters (add to it as you see fit)

`(?!.*\[)` ensures that no special character/space before the `[...]` section is replaced